# convert 2.7E+11 to number in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file and in some fields and numbers are not saved correctly. This should be a phone number 2.7E+11. This csv file is generated by ebay.

Comment: Can you add some code? Where is the issue happening - is it in the CSV being generated by eBay? In your processing code? Are you by any chance importing your file into Excel?

Comment: if all you've got it `2.7E+11`, then you're never going to get the original phone number back. But are you *sure* that's what the actual file contains? If you're viewing it in Excel, it might be just showing up that way in Excel; it might be perfectly fine. Try viewing the file in a text editor to double-check.

Comment: I try with number_format(2.7E+11,0,'','') but this return 0, and yes if i open the file in exel I see alot of this. On the item number,user phone number,custom label,transaction id. In the text edit/ sublime text 3 is the same

Comment: Well @Spudley suggested opening it up in a text editor, that should be your next step.

Comment: the text editor have the same numbers

Comment: So to clarify: if you take the original file you downloaded and view it in a text editor, you see `2.7E+11` as plain text in the file, instead of a phone number? If that's the case, then you've got bad data. There is absolutely no way in the world that you're going to get the original phone number back from that. All you can tell from that is that it started with `27` and has 11 digits. The rest of the digits are not there and can't be recovered from this format. If that's what you've got then you need to contact the original data provider and get them to send you the correct data.